# Affine cipher - Modular multiplicative inverse

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I want to decrypt an Affine cypher.

Definition: a^-1(c-b)

a = 5, b = 13

Range: Alphabet (26 letters)
Letter to decrypt: K (c = 10)

So:
= 5^-1(10-13)
= 5^-1(-3)

I am not sure what do to next.

My approach:
1.)
5^-1 mod 26 = 25
=> 25(-3) 
= 75 mod 26 
= 23?

2.)
= 5^-1 (-3)
= -15^-1
= -15 mod 26
= 1?

But the result should be 15!

Comment: But $5^{-1}$ cannot be $25$? After all $25\cdot5=125\equiv-5\pmod{26}$. The modular inverse is an integer $m$ such that $5m\equiv1\pmod{26}$.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. Finally I understand how to calculate the modular multiplicative inverse :)

Comment: Well done!${}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We see that $5\cdot 5=25\equiv -1\pmod{26}$. Therefore the inverse of $5$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{26}$ is $5^{-1}=-5$. Deciphering is then straight forward:
$$
a^{-1}(c-b)=(-5)(10-13)=(-5)\cdot(-3)=15.
$$